# Is this an optocoupler ans how do I identify the pins?

Tags: identification, opto-isolator

I bought an Arduino starter kit with some basic components, and I know among them is an optocoupler. I need one for my project, and the only thing resembling it is a chip marked 'L1513 LTV4N35.' How can I find out?

Comment: Using Google: (LTV4N35 / LTV4N37) NPN-OUTPUT DC-INPUT OPTOCOUPLER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's an opto. You can confirm by googling the part number and the word "datasheet": "LTV4N35 datasheet", and find the datasheet for the part. **https://www.arrow.com/en/products/ltv-4n35/lite-on-technology**

One of the pages in the datasheet will show the pinout:
[image: Pinout and Label]

If you're slightly lucky, the datasheet will even have examples of usage in a circuit and which external parts it needs connected to the pins (like resistors, clock crystal, capacitors, inductors, etc.)